# Applying an ID to a select build by AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Okay, so I built a select input as followed:

```
<select 
    id='change-connect-week-in-manage-panel-dropdown' 
    ng-change='changeConnectEditing()' class="form-control" 
    ng-model="connectData.connectId" 
    ng-options="opt.id as opt.name for opt in connectData.connects"
>
</select>
```

This builds the following:

```
<select 
    id="change-connect-week-in-manage-panel-dropdown" 
    ng-change="changeConnectEditing()" 
    class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched"   
    ng-model="connectData.connectId" 
    ng-options="opt.id as opt.name for opt in connectData.connects"
>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Week 15</option>
    <option value="1">Week 14</option>   
    <option value="2">Week 13</option>
    <option value="3">Week 12</option>
    <option value="4">Week 11</option>
</select>
```

I want to create this (Note the id attribute now on each option tag):

```
    <select 
    id="change-connect-week-in-manage-panel-dropdown" 
    ng-change="changeConnectEditing()" 
    class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched"   
    ng-model="connectData.connectId" 
    ng-options="opt.id as opt.name for opt in connectData.connects"
>
    <option id="1" value="0" selected="selected">Week 15</option>
    <option id="2" value="1">Week 14</option>   
    <option id="3" value="2">Week 13</option>
    <option id="4" value="3">Week 12</option>
    <option id="5" value="4">Week 11</option>
</select>
```

I've tried `ng-options="opt.id as opt.name for opt in connectData.connects track by opt.id"` but I can't figure out how to apply an id like you usually can with `{{$index}}` I'm not sure what else can be done. Thanks.

Comment: Both code boxes show the same :S

Comment: I think your second and third snippets are exactly the same. What do you mean by id for options? What difference providing id for option makes?

Comment: See it messes up even here :P

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-repeat` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) instead. `ng-options` will not allow you to add custom property to options.